# How to pass a paramater to the next GSP

Tags: grails, controller, parameter-passing, textfield, gsp

I have the below controller which redirects to another controller's action save()

```
class DaController {

static allowedMethods = [save: "POST", update: "POST", delete: "POST"]
........

def save() {
    def daInstance = new Da(params)
    if (!daInstance.save(flush: true)) {
        render(view: "create", model: [daInstance: daInstance])
        return 
    }

    flash.message = message(code: 'default.created.message', args: [message(code: 'da.label', default: 'Da'), daInstance.id])
    redirect(controller: "ligneDa" , action: "create", id: daInstance.id)
}
```

and i want to use `Da.id` in the page `create.gsp` (for ligneDa) (I will use it in a text field)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
render(view: "create", model: [daInstance: daInstance, daId: yourParameter])
```

And at gsp:

```
<input value="${daId} />
```

or

```
<input value="${daInstance.id} />
```

if it is same.

Comment: and how can i use this id in the textfield? what i put in the value?

Comment: i guess you didn't understand what i mean
i have a domain class named Da witch have in it controller an action save() witch redirect me to another controller LigneDa witch have a relation many to one with Da...so in the action create (that of ligneDa controller) i have a g:slect contains the list of Da and i have to chose one but i want to have a textfield wich have as value the Da.id of the current Da

Comment: So, what is problem? You can render create.gsp from create action of controller LigneDa with params (anything you want. params like [key:value]). At LigneDa you have Da.Id from save action, right?
Put at model: [daInstance: daInstance, daId: yourParameter] any parameter. At gsp use <g:select from="blabla" value="{paramNameFromControllerligneDa}/>

Comment: i try it but it doesn't work.
i use in save action render(view: "create", model: [daInstance: daInstance,daId:daInstance.getId()] and at _form.gsp i used <g:textField  name="da.id"  required="" value="${daId}"  /> but it doesn't work i have nothing in the textfield 
(thanks very much for helping me..i'm new in grails for that maybe something very easy but i can't do it)

Comment: you can try to render create.gsp from action "create" of controller LigneDa.